# How can i search for a value inside an object with using findOne in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

[image]

this is my MongoDB data

an I have to get the token->token data

```
const doc = JSON.parse(reqTest);
  const database = client.db("loginapi");
  const movies = database.collection("users");

const finder=await movies.findOne({token:{token:doc.token}});
```

I tried to use this but it didn't work.

Comment: Is `doc.token` a string or do you have to do `doc.token.token` to get the string?

Comment: doc.token is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `token` is an Object in your document, you have to use 'token.token' to match the strings.

```js
movies.findOne({ 'token.token': doc.token })
```

Comment: it worked like this thanks , `movies.findOne({ "token.token" :doc.token })`

Comment: Oh yeah, that's what I meant to do but I accidently left the object. I will edit answer.